# Steps for deploying a winforms C# application

Tags: deployment

I'm developing a windows forms c# application for a client with sqlexpress database. It contains simple CRUD operations using sql DataReader, DataWriter.  My problem is how to install the application for the client to use in the easiest way.

I'm going to install sql express and .net framework in the client PC. But I don't know the other steps. What files should I include for the client to use the application. Is there any other way??

I'm really confused, I've read many articles on the internet but I'm really lost now.

EDIT::the application will be used on one machine locally only

Comment: Have you found a tutorial that does something similar? Can you make it run? Can you modify it bit by bit to accomplish some of the things you want from your requirements?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it contains Just simple CRUD, why SQL ? you can use SQLite and no need to install anything .. Just .Net Framework, But if you already finish implementation, you will just need .Net Framework and the Database Server which will be local in your case.

Comment: if this answer your question, mark as solved to close the question and help other

Comment: tnx for ur reply. Yes, I'm already done with implementation but I'll consider sqlite for future projects. As for the current project if I installed the sql server and the .net express what files from my application should I copy to the client PC. When I try vs 2012 publish nothing shows up any alternatives??

Comment: Build your project as release mode and you will get a .exe file will your DLLs files, that what you will need .. read this will help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085437/how-do-i-publish-a-windows-forms-application

Comment: also make sure to add your connectionString in App.config to change it easily in client machine

Comment: any idea how to add it

Comment: Add new configuration file in your project .. But if you planned to connect local and it is simple project, no need for that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx